# Page slide effect is not working with page, it's only woking with <div> in jQuery. I want to use it in iphone application

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

Page slide effect is not working with page, it's only working with `<div>`. I want to use it in iPhone application.

Comment: Can you show us the code that's not working? What have you tried?

Comment: Please some specific example of what it is you're intending to do, how you're expecting it to work, and in what way it's failing.  HTML and JS code would also be nice.

Comment: God or you will know your exact problem